# Mongodb query grouping optimizations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm not very good at mongodb queries nor mongodb optimization so I'm searching whether my query could be somehow optimized.

I have collection of logs and I'd like to create some grouping query that will show how many of logs will expire in how many days for each tenant and organisation. One tenant can have multiple organisations.

This is how my java object looks like:

```java
public class MetaData {

  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @Indexed
  private UUID tenantId;

  @Indexed
  private UUID orgId;  

  @Indexed
  private String filename;

  @Indexed
  private OffsetDateTime uploadTime;

}
```

I like to have some data like:

```json
{
  "tenantId": "UUID",
  "orgId": "UUID",
  "expirations": [{
      "expireInDays": 1,
      "logsCount": 5
    },
    {
      "expireInDays": 2,
      "logsCount": 5
    },
    {
      "expireInDays": 3,
      "logsCount": 5
    },
    {
      "expireInDays": 4,
      "logsCount": 5
    },
  ]
}
```

```json
db.getCollection('metadata').aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "uploadTime": {
                $gt: ISODate("2021-02-28"),
                $lt: ISODate("2021-04-28"),
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "tenantId": "$tenantId",
            "orgId": "$orgId",
            "days": {
                $trunc: {
                    $divide: [
                        {
                            $subtract: [
                                "$uploadTime",
                                ISODate("2021-02-28")
                            ]
                        },
                        86400000
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "tenantId": "$tenantId",
                "orgId": "$orgId",
                "days": "$days"
            },
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                tenantId: "$_id.tenantId",
                orgId: "$_id.orgId",
            },
            "expirations": {
                $push: {
                    "expireInDays": "$_id.days",
                    "logsCount": {
                        $sum: "$count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            tenantId: "$_id.tenantId",
            orgId: "$_id.orgId",
            expirations: "$expirations"
        }
    }
],
    {
        allowDiskUse: true
    });
```

The thing is that it needs to write to the disk because of high volume of data and currently such query takes ~1 minute. I'm not quite sure if the grouping is written as best as it could be. My main concern is with the day computation and grouping. So can I somehow improve this?

Answer (score 0):

The below query will reduce the execution time.

I would advise you to perform the below indexes to further improve the execution time:

**Index - 1**

```js
db.getCollection('metadata').createIndex({"uploadTime": -1})
```

> Apply `partialIndexFilter` if possible and include that condition in `$match` stage

**Index - 2**

```js
db.getCollection('metadata').createIndex({
  "tenantId": 1,
  "orgId": 1,
})
```

> Not sure if this will work, give it a try and check if it improves performance

**Query:**

```js
db.getCollection('metadata').aggregate([
{
  "$match": {
    "uploadTime": {
      $gt: ISODate("2021-01-28"),
      $lt: ISODate("2021-04-28"),
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    "_id": {
      "tenantId": "$tenantId",
      "orgId": "$orgId",
      "expireInDays": {
        $trunc: {
          $divide: [
            {
              $subtract: [
                "$uploadTime",
                ISODate("2021-02-28")
              ]
            },
            86400000
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "count": {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    "_id": {
      tenantId: "$_id.tenantId",
      orgId: "$_id.orgId",
    },
    "expirations": {
      $push: {
        "expireInDays": "$_id.expireInDays",
        "logsCount": {
          $sum: "$count",
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
// Handle `$projection` pipeline from java, this will save you some time.
// {
//     $project: {
//         _id: 0,
//         tenantId: "$_id.tenantId",
//         orgId: "$_id.orgId",
//         expirations: "$expirations"
//     }
// }
], {
  allowDiskUse: true
});
```

Comment: You need to add $sort stage to the pipeline for the second index (tenantId_orId) to work "sometimes" as they spell it in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes

Comment: Ah, and version matters. Indexes work only for 1st stage in mongodb v4.0 and older. No chance to use indexes for $group stage there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing it out, I didn't know that earlier. I always assumed that things work since I am always using the latest version.

Comment: index for uploadTime is already there `@Indexed` annotation is doing that. Also indexes for `tenantId` and `orgId` are there but just standalone. Will it make some difference to use them as compound? Btw I'm running this on mongo atlas so it's probable the latest mongo available.

Comment: v4.0 is still available for dedicated (m10+) tiers. The shared ones are all on 4.4 but performance there can vary depending on load from other users.

Comment: Hmm that compound index `tenantId_orgId` is not being used even when I add sort before first group. Those conditions mentioned in docs are weird.

Comment: @bilak Sorry, my bad, I missed the last condition there "The only accumulator used in the $group stage is $first.". Your accumulator is $sum. No dice.